# xamarin android bindings changing a classes final int field to a c# enum

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, java-binding

I've been writing a Xamaring Bindings Library for a third party Android JAR and become stumped at how to convert an int field in a class to an enum.

I've created a C# enum for the int fields using EnumFields.xml and have also got this successfully return out of methods using EnumMethods.xml but in one place a class is instead returned which exposes an int field which should be my enum.

I've tried:

```
<method jni-name="error" parameter="return" clr-enum-type=....
```

Within EnumMethods but couldnt get it to work, i then tried

```
<attr path=".......[@name='Result']/field[@name='error']"
    name="managedType">
```

Within Metadata.xml but also couldn't get it to map. I can change its property name but not its return type.

Within the JavaDoc it says the following:

> public final int error

And in my generated C# I get:

```
// Metadata.xml XPath field reference: path="/api/package[@name='cn.com.aratek.util']/class[@name='Result']/field[@name='error']"
```

Have I missed something obvious?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/

Comment: Hi @LeonLu-MSFT I'm not sure what you are adding to my question? I've actually used the link and the one on the microsoft docs to get to where I am. I just can't see how to change a field of type final int to the enum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A year later I ended up stumbling across my own post after hitting the same issue again.
For reference my error was trying to use `managedType` as the name.  You simply use `type`.

e.g within metadata.xml

```
<attr path=".......[@name='Result']/field[@name='error']" name="type">NewEnumName</attr>
```

References I used to help figure this out:

- https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb - great
  resource with lots of examples
- The updated Microsoft documentation
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata
- Finally, simply looking at other peoples source on git hub. the
  GTK# bindings particularly 
  https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp/blob/master/gtk/Gtk.metadata